# Should I remove the front side of the case?

Tags: fan, desktop-computer, temperature, case

Hey I hope I am in the right community.
I have this PC case(CASE CORSAIR OBSIDIAN SERIES 750D FULL TOWER ATX BLACK):
[image: CASE CORSAIR OBSIDIAN SERIES 750D FULL TOWER ATX BLACK]

And I am wondering if I should have the front side of the case open so the 2 fans in the above picture will be visible, at least while using the pc.

In the picture below you can see how it is when the front is closed:
[image]

It might not affect it at all but I wanna know what is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The design of the case looks to have gaps around the front panel to allow air to flow into the case. As such, you shouldn't need to have the front panel removed whilst the machine is in operation (I'm sure they wouldn't have put a front panel on there if it was seriously detrimental to the operation of the machine.) With the panel in place I suspect the machine sounds slightly quieter and looks neater.

That said, you could easily conduct your own tests of this, by monitoring your system temps whilst the machine is in operation both with and without the panel in place. I would always suggest doing this after a new build anyway to be sure the cooling in your machine is sufficient and heatsinks are correctly seated.

Comment: There's also a fine mesh in front of the fans which needs to be removed & cleaned periodically; so removing the cover would look doubly ugly, as you'd still have the mesh. [There's another under the PSU too]

Answer (score 0):

Removing parts of the case may make cooling *worse*. The fans are designed to pull air through the case and over components that need cooling. When you remove part of the case, you're decreasing the fan-powered airflow and relying on convection instead, which is much less efficient.